# PHP can't unlink file after fclose

Tags: php, fopen, unlink, rm, fclose

After my script finishes I can delete the file, but while it's running I can't touch it, even after an `fclose()`. Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
    $Files = glob("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/files/*.csv");

    $File = fopen($Files[0], "r");        

    //while (($Data = fgetcsv($File)) !== false) {...

    $i = 0;
    while (is_resource($File)) {
        $i && sleep(1);
        echo "Closing handle.\n";
        fclose($File);
        if (++$i > 5)
            die("Could not close handle.");
    }

foreach ($Files as $File) {
    $i = 0;
    while (file_exists($File)) {
        $i && sleep(1);
        echo "Deleting file.\n";
        @unlink($File);
        echo 'www-data@debian:~$ ', $Command = "rm -f '$File' 2>&1", "\n", shell_exec($Command);
        if (++$i > 5)
            die("Could not delete the file.");
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to delete it through `unlink()` and using shell commands and neither are working, both give me this error:

> rm: cannot remove
>   'invincible-file.csv':
>   Text file busy

I also realize the script might be a bit overkill, but that's purely because I couldn't get it to work in any way, and some of the extra code is just for output purposes to try and debug what is happening.

Comment: What is the content of `$Files`? Also, you use `fopen` with the "r" mode for reading and you are trying to delete the file later. Are you sure that the user has permission to delete? Maybe it's a permission issue. Try doing the `unlink` without any of the other code.

Comment: Remove the `@` before the `unlink` so you can let php tell you why it failed. Also, check the return value of `fclose`.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Thanks for helping me so far, I'm going to try your `unlink` without the `fopen` at all, and I've added even more code to the example, hopefully I'm not missing any more important parts

Comment: @chiliNUT I've already done that, I get my xdebug output that gives the same error

Comment: @KodosJohnson If I remove the `fopen`, etc. it deletes all of the files without any issues. It's only once I open and close the file withing the PHP script that I can no longer delete it

Comment: What is the underlying filesystem on which `invincible-file.csv` resides?

Comment: @bishop underlying is NTFS, it's on the host machine that this web server is running from (a Debian Virtual Box, folder shared through the Virtual Box shared folders)

Comment: Did you try chiliNUT's suggestion of checking the return value of `fclose`? It should be true.

Comment: @KodosJohnson no I didn't get that far, I tried the answer out and it fixed the problem I was having

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've run into this issue before and been able to remedy by forcing garbage collection after closing the file and before unlinking it:

```
gc_collect_cycles();
```

By far not the best solution, but it did resolve an issue I had deleting files that had been previously opened and closed lines before.

Comment: Wow that worked, no where else could I find this function to run after `fclose()` but that worked without a hiccup, thank you for that

Comment: do you think that additionally that clearing the cache (`clearstatcache`) would assist with this sort of overrun issue?

Comment: @BrianLeishman Would you please try `fflush` before the `fclose`, without the `gc_collect_cycles` hack?

Comment: The problem also happens with files created with touch, the same solution worked for it too. I used to touch a file as a mutex to prevent same script from overlapping if run more than once at the same time. I wasn't able to unlink at the end of the script.