# PHP unlink() files after it is added to ZipArchive

Tags: php, php-ziparchive, unlink

I am adding multiple files to a ZipArchive each file has a unique name.

**Controller:**

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipPath, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$filesToClose = $this->advancedService->addFiles($files, $zip);
$zip->close();

foreach ($filesToClose as $file) {
    fclose($file);
    unlink(stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri']);
}
// return response
```

**Service:**

```
// addFiles function
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileName = 'FILE_'.$file->getId().'.'.$file->getExtension();

    $tempFile = tmpfile();
    $content = file_get_contents('uriFromSdk');
    fwrite($tempFile, $content);
    $zipArchive->addFile(stream_get_meta_data($tempFile)['uri'], $fileName);

    $filesToClose[] = $tempFile;
}

return $filesToClose;
```

In controller I get this error:

`stream_get_meta_data(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource`

The main problem is I can not close or delete any file before `$zip->close()`, How can I unlink the files from the server ?

Keep in mind `fclose()` doesn't throw this error, only the `stream_get_meta_data()`.

Thanks.

Comment: What does reversing order of `fclose` and `unlink` do? First `unlink` then `fclose`? [`stream_get_meta_data`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) requires an active stream.

Comment: I have not tried that, do you think it matters ? if yes can you please explain thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse order of [`fclose`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) and [`unlink`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php). First `unlink` then `fclose`. [`stream_get_meta_data`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) requires an active stream.

> Returns information about an existing stream.

```
foreach ($filesToClose as $file) {
    unlink(stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri']);
    fclose($file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bloodyKnuckles's answer about stream_get_meta_data is correct, but as far as I know `unlink` can be done if the file is not used/busy. So you may need like this:

```
foreach ($filesToClose as $file) {
    $filepath = stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri'];
    fclose($file);
    unlink($filepath);
}
```

If it still has an error, try adding `gc_collect_cycles()` after `fclose`:

```
foreach ($filesToClose as $file) {
    $filepath = stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri'];
    fclose($file);
    gc_collect_cycles();
    unlink($filepath);
}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251652/php-cant-unlink-file-after-fclose)